# using xmlHttp.open() but nothing happends

Tags: javascript, ajax

When I run the function newuser() it should send some information back to a index.php file. But when I run it nothing happens.. I've tried so many ways to find out what's wrong, but no luck. Can any of you spot something wrong in this code? Or an other way I should code it?

```
function newuser() {

            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                name = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("name").value);
                company = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("company").value);
                nationality = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("nationality").value);
                phonenumber = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("phonenumber").value);

                queryString = "name=" + name + "&company=" + company + "&nationalities=" + nationality + "&phonenumber=" + phonenumber + "&URL=newuser";
                xmlHttp.open("GET", "index.php?" + queryString, true);
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerRespons;
                xmlHttp.send();

           }else{
               setTimeout('newuser()', 1000)
           }  
    }

function handleServerRespons(){

    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4){

        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 200){

            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.rsponseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement=xmlResponse.documentElement;
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;

            document.getElementById("underinput").innerHTML = message;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerRespons;` - is your `handleServerRespons` function declaration misspelled as well?

Comment: And are you sure you want to share some global `xmlHttp`? Why don't you instantiate it inside of `newuser` so a new one is created for each function call?

Comment: Did you check your console for any errors?

Comment: i got this code right from thenewboston.org, so if it's better to not call a global xmlHttp, then i will do it your way. what do you mean by putting it inside new user? cause this code is only called once

Comment: redyState is misspelled -- you mean readyState.  Same with sersponseXML.

Comment: in the second function, correct the syntax error, change the [if (xmlHttp.redyState == 4){] to [if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4){]

I mean the redyState to readyState

Comment: thanks! but still, it wont work :/

Comment: Also change `(xmlHttp.redyState == 200)` to `(xmlHttp.readyState == 200)`

Comment: but it looks like it doesn't send the data to index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your querystring is wrong (too many question marks characters on it). Change it to this:

```
queryString = "name=" + name + "&company=" + company + "&nationalities=" + nationality + "&phonenumber=" + phonenumber + "&URL=newuser";
xmlHttp.open("GET", "index.php?" + queryString, true);
```

Comment: you must have more errors in your code... Check your browsers console for errors...

Comment: I find this hard to believe, especially with all the misspellings found in your code...  What browser/browser version are you using?

Comment: i use chrome newest version, and JavaScript Errors Notifier 1.7 for error detection

Comment: figured it out! had a misspelling in the php code! Thanks for any help!